# Unable to get Count comma separated data in mysql length of character

Tags: mysql

```
declare variable varchar (50);
declare  loopcount int;
declare i int;
declare GrouPID int ;
set variable=(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT groupId)
FROM EventList_View);
 SET loopcount=
  (select LENGTH(variable) - LENGTH(REPLACE(variable, ',', ''))); 
      select   loopcount;
```

in variable i am getting data '1,6,8' but when i try to count length  i am getting null,  even i have declare all variable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574

Answer (score 0):

I think your GROUP_CONCAT, requires a GROUP BY in the query.
Are you not getting any errors?

Comment: NO Stil Its not working same  i have apply group by then also i am getting  data in variable